# How to request the Garbage Collector in node.js to run?

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection

At startup, it seems my node.js app uses around 200MB of memory. If I leave it alone for a while, it shrinks to around 9MB.

Is it possible from within the app to:

1. Check how much memory the app is using ?
2. Request the garbage collector to run ?

The reason I ask is, I load a number of files from disk, which are processed temporarily. This probably causes the memory usage to spike. But I don't want to load more files until the GC runs, otherwise there is the risk that I will run out of memory.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: How are you loading these files? If you need to load a huge file, you must use the Stream approach and you can process the file while still reading. Have you consider it?

Comment: @well That was 3 years ago. I'm working on some other project now and can't remember much about it.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

If you launch the node process with the `--expose-gc` flag, you can then call `global.gc()` to force node to run garbage collection.  Keep in mind that all other execution within your node app is paused until GC completes, so don't use it too often or it will affect performance.

You might want to include a check when making GC calls from within your code so things don't go bad if node was run without the flag:

```
if (global.gc) {
    global.gc();
} else {
    console.log('Garbage collection unavailable.  Pass --expose-gc '
      + 'when launching node to enable forced garbage collection.');
}
```

Comment: Where the docs for "--expose-gc"? I am not  find any docs in nodejs.org.

Comment: @pea3nut it's a option of the V8 runtime, which node uses. This and other options can be listed with `node --v8-options`

Comment: You have to pass true to the function for full GC otherwise it will just do a minor GC

Comment: @PiyushBalapure, do you have any reference about gc() arguments ?

Comment: I am yet to see the documentation for the gc() arguments. Did not even find it in V8 docs. I read about full GC here https://nodesource.com/blog/request-garbage-collection-for-node-js-processes-with-n-solid

Comment: FWIW, passing `true` (these days, at least) effects a _minor_ collection: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/5421e15bdc6122420d90ec462c3622b57d59c9d6/deps/v8/src/extensions/gc-extension.cc#L65-L71

Comment: When would the catch block run? If `--expose-gc` is missing then `global.gc` will just be undefined

Comment: @evandrix edited this answer and Pique's answer. They were seemingly trying to combine them (why??) and ended up making them identically broken. Those edits need to be reverted.

Comment: "Keep in mind that all other execution within your node app is paused until GC completes" -- what other execution are you referring to (apart from worker threads)? Do you simply mean this method is blocking (and takes a while to return) and as-such, the event loop won't be processing other callbacks until it completes?

Comment: Guys it's 2022, `global?.gc()` suffices

Comment: What’s the point of doing `try`–`catch`ing when you’re already checking `if (global.gc)`?

Comment: @AliMertÇakar it is not `global` that is possibly `undefined`, it is the `gc` property.

Comment: Good point, you can also optionally call a function. like `global?.gc?.()`

Answer (score 7):

When you cannot pass the `--expose-gc` flag to your node process on start for any reason, you may try this:

```js
import { setFlagsFromString } from 'v8';
import { runInNewContext } from 'vm';

setFlagsFromString('--expose_gc');
const gc = runInNewContext('gc'); // nocommit
gc();
```

Notes:

- This worked for me in node 16.x
- You may want to check [process.memoryUsage()](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processmemoryusage) before and after running the gc
- Use with care: Quote from the node docs [v8.setFlagsFromString](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/v8.html#v8setflagsfromstringflags):

> This method should be used with care. Changing settings after the VM has started may result in unpredictable behavior, including crashes and data loss; or it may simply do nothing.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. Really helpful when writing unit tests that are run by IDE and you don't have control over node arguments.