# WeakMap inverted

Tags: javascript, weak-references, weakmap

Is there a way to create WeakMap of any other weak references in Javascript for storing key value pairs where **key is String/Number** and value is Object.

The referencing would have to work something like this:

```
const wMap = new WeakRefMap();
const referencer = {child: new WeakRefMap()}
wMap.set('child', temp.child);
wMap.has('child'); // true
delete referencer.child
wMap.has('child'); //false
```

I creating kind of a tree structure that holds track of references that are still used in the current scope.

I will do a lot of merging, and recursively cleaning up a deeply nested structure can be very inefficient for this use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it by using [WeakRef](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakRef) and [FinalizationRegistry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/FinalizationRegistry).

Here is an example written in TypeScript:

```
class InvertedWeakMap<K extends string | symbol, V extends object> {
  _map = new Map<K, WeakRef<V>>()
  _registry: FinalizationRegistry<K>

  constructor() {
    this._registry = new FinalizationRegistry<K>((key) => {
      this._map.delete(key)
    })
  }

  set(key: K, value: V) {
    this._map.set(key, new WeakRef(value))
    this._registry.register(value, key)
  }

  get(key: K): V | undefined {
    const ref = this._map.get(key)
    if (ref) {
      return ref.deref()
    }
  }

  has(key: K): boolean {
    return this._map.has(key) && this.get(key) !== undefined
  }
}

async function main() {
  const map = new InvertedWeakMap()
  let data = { hello: "world!" } as any
  map.set("string!", data)

  console.log('---before---')
  console.log(map.get("string!"))
  console.log(map.has("string!"))

  data = null
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0))
  global.gc() // call gc manually

  console.log('---after---')
  console.log(map.get("string!"))
  console.log(map.has("string!"))
}

main()
```

It must be run with the [--expose-gc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30654451/3604570) option in the node.js environment.

Comment: That's a nice example! 
Lot of new features in JavaScript since 5 years ago when I was trying to find a solution for this=). 
Here is a codepen of the code example above https://codepen.io/jEnbuska/pen/jOxzZbm

Answer (score 1):

You cannot catch a delete operation. What you could do would be encapsuling the data in another obj e.g.

```
function referenceTo(value){
 this.value=value;
}
```

So if this one reference is deleted, it cant be accessed anymore

```
var somedata=new referenceTo(5)
var anotherref=somedata;
//do whatever
delete somedata.value;
//cannot be accessed anymore
anotherref.value;//undefined
```

Comment: To my understanding that does not solve the issue of deleting nested structures when top one is deleted?
ps. I fixed the example, the previous was invalid.
I don't get it why es6 WeakMap does not take strings as keys and objects as values. Doesn't seem to add any value on everyday programming.

Comment: @nabuska yeah you may need to filter somewhen.