# How to properly recycle a buffer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

This simple code makes app crash with out of memory:

```
var buf;
console.log(process.memoryUsage())
for(i=0; i<10000000; i++){
    buf = Buffer.alloc(1024)
    buf.clear
    delete buf
    buf = null
}
console.log(process.memoryUsage())
```

So how properly recycle the buffer so it can be reused?
Not sure if clear or delete are appropriate methods but how then?
Thank you

Comment: Is the goal to avoid garbage collecting?

Comment: That code is working fine for me: `node v10.15.1`. What version are you using?, Not running out of memory, and the memory footprint is quite low.

Comment: Working for me on node v8.9.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the answers, the buffer does not have a `clear()` method to un-allocate/free the allocated buffer memory. You can **request** the Node's gc to free-up the unused memory by calling gc() method but that option is only available when your application is started with **--expose-gc** flag.

```
'use strict';
let buf;
console.log(process.memoryUsage());
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {

    buf = Buffer.alloc(1024);
    // Do your stuff
}

if (global.gc) {
    console.log('Requesting gc to free-up unsed memory');
    global.gc(); // Synchronous call, may take longer time and further execution get blocked till it finishes the execution
}

console.log(process.memoryUsage());
```

Links: [How to request the Garbage Collector in node.js to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321997/how-to-request-the-garbage-collector-in-node-js-to-run)