# Using promises in an infinite loop (without leaking memory)

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, es6-promise, infinite-loop

I am attempting to write a function that waits for a promise to execute, executes the promise, and then start to wait for the promise to execute again.

I have tried a few looping examples, but all seem to have caused memory leaks.

This is a mock for a library that I am using.

```
const waitForMessage = (topics, cb) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb(null, query, "test/request")
    }, 250);
}
```

Which I converted to a standard es6 Promise.

```
const waitForRequest = () =>
    new Promise((res, rej) =>
        waitForMessage([], (err, query, topic) =>
            err ? rej(query, topic) : res(query, topic)));
```

And this seems to work fine....

The Problem seems to be when I try iterating over this infinitely...

Conceptually, I would like to do something like this (which has [documented issues](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/issues/179#issuecomment-93453094) in the specification)

```
// Warning: JS implementation will leak memory!!!
const loop = () =>
    waitForRequest()
        .then(() => loop());

loop();
```

However, I have found that even a synchronous loop seems to produce a simular memory leak here...

```
const handleEvent = () =>
    waitForRequest()
        .then((query, topic) => graphql(schema, query))
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(`graphql -> recieved data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(`ERROR: ${err}`)
        });

const run = async () => {
    while (true) {
        await handleEvent()
    }
}

run();
```

I sampled the heap profile and found the top down call stack to be...

```
- [14.5%] emitHook
- [0%] (anon)
  - [0%] handleEvent
    - [0%] then
      - [0%] emitInitNative
        - [69.45%] add    <- where the majority of the heap is being allocated.
    - [0%] waitForRequest
      - [0%] Promise
        - [0%] (anon)
          - [0%] waitForMessage
            - [0%] setTimeout
              - [16%] insert
```

Which seems to imply that the `.then()` and ultimately the `.add()` call is consuming about `70%` of the heap (and growing...). As I sample the heap, it seems as it is growing at a rate of `1-7 kB/s`.

How can squash this memory leak? Or is there a better design pattern to use for this type of situation? Any help is appreciated, still relatively new to using javascript.

Comment: Did the garbage collector run inbetween?

Comment: I believe so... I was monitoring the heap over a good amount of time (so I assume it should have run). However, I do not have any code that interacts with the gc.

Comment: With the Chrome developer tools you can trigger a gc cycle. If you are unsure wether a gc cycle happened, you actually don't even know wether you are leaking memory.

Comment: I am using the node remote debugging with chrome tools (chrome://inspect) to log the heap - I don't actually see the option to trigger it, I have just been profiling the heap over time (and looking at the node process and how much it is allocating in top)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321997/how-to-request-the-garbage-collector-in-node-js-to-run