# Why blob.arrayBuffer doesn't release the used memory?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a code that records camera input from client into server as such :

```
async function saveIntoMp4(chunks) {
    const options = {
        type: "video/webm"
    }
    let blob = new Blob(chunks, options);
    chunks.length = 0 // to stop any memory leaks
    const buffer = Buffer.from(await blob.arrayBuffer());
    try {
        fs.writeFile(
            `./videos/1.mp4`,
            buffer,
            () => console.log("video is saved!")
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

However buffer take up the memory and doesn't let go of it on my Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. Everytime I run this function it keeps occupying more and more memory. I have no instance of `console.log` from the buffer or chunks or blob or any kind. I am not sure why the memory is not released and what I should do about it. I have used nodejs version 20 and 18.9 so far without any luck. Why blob.arrayBuffer doesn't release the used memory?

Comment: As you use chunks, you're repeatedly calling the saveIntoMp4() function I believe, and each time it creates a new buffer, the memory usage will keep increasing until the garbage collector is triggered. Garbage Collector will not release the memory immediately, it might take some time.

Btw, rather than buffering the entire file in memory, you could consider using a streaming approach to process and save the video data.

Comment: Have you redacted anything such as referring to/saving the blob reference in the writeFile callback or a console log of the buffer? Also recommend you inspect in Chrome devtools and take heap snapshots and check since that should GC between, or force GC https://stackoverflow.com/a/30654451/414062 but chrome will be better to explore the memory (you need to run node process with --inspect flag)

Comment: No the function that calls saveIntoMp4() happens only on one instance each time. Chunks are pushed into a chunk array separately. The only I can see no leakage is by removing await blob.arrayBuffer() from the code which is debilitating

Comment: @Dominic the same code works fine with no leakage on Windows. On Ubuntu I have tried to servers from 2 different providers and a person vmachine. On all I see the massive leakage. The entire arraybuffer remains in memory.