# Why memory keeps increasing while using Nodejs on Linux?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a little piece of code as such :

```
async function saveIntoMp4(chunks) {
    const options = {
        type: "video/webm"
    }
    let blob = new Blob(chunks, options);
    chunks.length = 0 // to stop any memory leaks
    const buffer = Buffer.from(await blob.arrayBuffer());
    try {
        fs.writeFile(
            `./videos/1.mp4`,
            buffer,
            () => console.log("video is saved!")
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

And everytime this function is called the occupied memory of mine goes up. It reached 4gb in fact. I have tracked the heap usage with node --inspect and I realized that `arrayBuffer` is infact emptied out without an issue. Yet the memory that started at 75mb reached more than 100mb just by calling the function once as is shown in the picture. Is this a memory leak? How can I stop this from happening. I have tested it on Ubuntu 20 / 22 / Centos 9 and Rocky linux ( red hat variant ) all the same situation. The only place I am not facing memory issues is my windows 11. :

[image]

Comment: *"How can I stop this from happening."* - stop worrying about it? nodejs garbage collection will do its job when it needs to or [call it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30654451). though, i do curious your nodejs version - some build might have bugs or regression.

Comment: @BagusTesa I called it manually as well by calling global.gc() in an interval of a minute. It went up to 4gb at one point. The server rebooted itself. It just does not work.

Comment: wait, server? is it on idle or swarmed by request? often times its not programming mistake but someone ran ddos against your server.

Comment: @BagusTesa No, server is only accessible from my ip and I am the only one using it. I am pretty sure of that. There is some leakage that I cannot figure out.

Comment: may we know what this `chunks` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so this had been bothering me for 10 days, I believe this had something to do with the memory allocator according to https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4375

I installed *libjemalloc* through *apt-get* on Ubuntu 20 by

> echo "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.2" >>
> /etc/ld.so.preload

and checked using

> ps aux | grep node cat /proc//smaps | grep jemalloc

The problem seems to be fixed.